# vba excel UserForm_Initialize()

Tags: excel, vba

In this code the following happens:

1. When the UserForm is opened, the value in cell E2 is retrieved and displayed in TextBox1.
2. The user enters a new value in TextBox1 which is stored in cell E2.

Code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Save_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Value = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Questions:
If the user moves cell E2 to e.g. B5, TextBox1 will still load the value from cell E2 (which is now empty).
Is it possible to get TextBox1 to retrieve the value from the new location of cell E2, which is now found in cell B5, without making manual changes to the code?

I have asked chatGPT but no useful answer has been given.

Comment: Name the cell, and use that name in the code rather than the address.

Comment: Of course, don't know why I didn't think of that, thanks  :-)
Could it be a problem if there are many defined names in the .xlsm file?

Comment: It shouldn't be, unless you reach thousands of names.